# How to do logical operation between DataFrame and Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, logical-operators

Suppose I have a bool `DataFrame df` and a bool `Series x` with the same index, and I want to do logical operation between `df` and `x` per column. Is there any short and fast way like `DataFrame.sub` compare to using `DataFrame.apply`?

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
       x      y      z      u
A  False  False   True   True
B   True   True   True   True
C   True  False  False  False

In [32]: x
Out[32]: 
A     True
B    False
C     True
dtype: bool

In [33]: r = df.apply(lambda col: col & x) # Any other way ??

In [34]: r
Out[34]: 
       x      y      z      u
A  False  False   True   True
B  False  False  False  False
C   True  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html), but need cast to `int` and then to `bool`, because `UserWarning`:

```
print (df.astype(int).mul(x.values, axis=0).astype(bool))
       x      y      z      u
A  False  False   True   True
B  False  False  False  False
C   True  False  False  False
```

Similar solution:

```
print (df.mul(x.astype(int), axis=0).astype(bool))
       x      y      z      u
A  False  False   True   True
B  False  False  False  False
C   True  False  False  False
```

---

```
print (df.mul(x.values, axis=0))
       x      y      z      u
A  False  False   True   True
B  False  False  False  False
C   True  False  False  False
```

> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expressions.py:181: UserWarning: evaluating in Python space because the '*' operator is not supported by numexpr for the bool dtype, use '&' instead
>         unsupported[op_str]))

Another `numpy` solution with [`np.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
print (pd.DataFrame(np.logical_and(df.values, x.values[:, None]), 
                                   index=df.index, 
                                   columns=df.columns))

       x      y      z      u
A  False  False   True   True
B  False  False  False  False
C   True  False  False  False
```